# Does Azure App Services support NetCore 2.2 InProc hosting?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I read that .NET Core 2.2 InProcess hosting had an issue (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2-known-issues.md)) in Azure.  The suggestion was to switch to OutOfProcess hosting.  Has this issue been fixed?   Can we use InProcess hosting yet?

Answer (score 1):

1) .NET Core 2.2 is now available in all regions for **public** App Service (Windows)

2) .NET Core 2.2 is also now available for all App Service Environments running in 
   **public** App Service.

3) .NET Core 2.2 is also now available for all sovereign cloud regions.

More details on .NET Core 2.2 features here:
[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-2-2/](http://More%20details%20on%20.NET%20Core%202.2%20features%20here:%20[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-2-2/])

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this has been fixed. We can use In-process with .NET Core 2.2

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/net-core-2-2-is-now-available-for-app-service-on-windows/